# mod_rewrite image protection

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

So i'm building a website where users can see a preview of an image in a smaller size, and they have to register to see the full resolution.

I don't thumbnail the images, i just load the whole image, and scale it. Since the images are low-res, this isn't really a problem.

The problem is that users can just right-click on the image en choose 'open in new tab' and they got it. I want to disable that in a way that .jpg and .gif files can be seen in the browser, in an -tag, but not when they try to enter the path in the address bar.

I'm on Apache.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a thumbnailed version and a large version. When you down-size it you only downsize the display of it. The full-size image is actually already on their computer.

Comment: That's not really a problem. My audience isn't good at all with computers. And even it that'd happen a couple of times, it's not a big deal. Im just wondering if i can protect it a little better with mod_rewrite. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^$
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http://www.yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http://yourdomain.com/.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule   ^/PublicFiles/*$ /page-about-direct-links.html
```

untested

Comment: Thanks Chris, i'm not near my work computer but when i tested it i'll let you know.

Comment: I see that you want to prevent the "view in new tab" -- checking the referrer like this won't work in that case because the referrer will probably still be set to your site.

In any case it is trivial to defeat this kind of protection if someone really wants to. The referrer is set by the client so you can change it at-will with no server interaction at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change the approach:

1. If you are showing small image, never use the original image. This will take longer to load and it`s a bad habbit. Use thumbnail instead, save bandwidth, speed the page.
2. Move the original pictures otside the web folder. This way they can`t be accessed sirectly via a link.
3. Make a php script that will load the original image if the user is registered.

mod_rewrite can`t check if the user is registered or logged. As for the Apache "[basic authentican](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)" can be used (but not the best way to do the thing).

```
function getImageFromOutside ( $homePath, $file )
{
    if ( file_exists ( $homePath . '/' . $file ) )
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents ( $homePath . '/' . $file );
        return $contents;
    }
}
$homePath = 'some_path/img';

if ( isset ( $_GET['uid'] ) )
{
    $img = $_GET['uid'] . '.jpeg';
    header ( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
    echo getImageFromOutside( $homePath, $img );
} else {
    print_r ( $_GET );
    echo file_exists ( $homePath . '/' . $file );
}
```

Tested, with folder structure

- root

  - img
  - publichtml

Comment: Interested in this myself. How do you move the pics outside the web folder but still view them through the site?

Comment: You can have folders outside the web folder like logs etc. PHP has the same read/write permissions as you have, and can access files in those folders.

Comment: So I could have an image outside of my 'publichtml' folder (which is my root directory)and I could still access from my site? How would I reference it?

Comment: This is a "good" practice see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382695/placing-php-script-outside-website-root http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822457/why-are-codeigniter-application-files-in-the-public-html-folder http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=280437.0